# How to specify the number of columns in datatables jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I downloaded datatables jquery plugin, and I tried to reduce the number of columns from the default six [image: Default] to just four [image: Edited to 4], from the html source code. After doing this, when I reload my page, it returned an error: [image]. How do I resolve this???

I have checked datatables website, but I don't really understand how to get this fixed. I'm a newbie in jQuery and this is my first time to use datatables plugin.

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ld0ae2g/)

Comment: That fiddle is a mess - even if it did work, it bears no relation to what you've shown in those images.  Here's a [working version](https://jsfiddle.net/markps/41pz6k3z/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are missing a < td > (line 248).

```
<tr>
  <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
  <td>here is the error</td>
  <td>37</td>
  <td>2008/12/11</td>
</tr>
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ld0ae2g/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You should check datatables documentation:https://www.datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4

It explained there that

DataTables warning: table id={id} - Requested unknown parameter '{parameter}' for row {row-index}, column{column-index}`

{id} is replaced with the DOM id of the table that has triggered the error
{parameter} is the name of the data parameter DataTables is requesting

{row-index} is the DataTables internal row index (row().index()) for the row that has triggered the error.

{column-index} is the column data index (column().index()) for the column that has triggered the error.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I have already checked the documentation. I do not understand where to correct, you can see in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/markps/41pz6k3z/). Remember I stated that I do not know anything about datatables and jQuery.

Comment: It means that in row 39 there is an error - as the MaVROSCy discover it.